# Using depenency in JSP File (Basic Maven)

Tags: java, jsp, maven, tomcat, maven-2

I'm trying to teach myself maven so I don't have to deal with all the dependency issues as has been recommended to me on SO, but I'm running into the same issue. I am trying to get a basic webapp going. I have this in my pom file:

```
<!--  Gson: Java to Json conversion -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.3</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

and this in my index.jsp:

```
<%@ page import="com.google.code.gson.*"%>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<%
Gson gson = new Gson();
%>
</body>
</html>
```

And I get this when I deploy:

```
An error occurred at line: 7 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Gson cannot be resolved to a type
4: <h2>Hello World!</h2>
5: <%="sorta"%>
6: <%
7: Gson gson = new Gson();
8: %>
9: </body>
10: </html>
```

I am sure I am just not understanding the basics of how this sort of thing works, but I feel as though it should work, as this is why I decided to learn maven in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, `Gson` is in a package called `com.google.gson`. Change the import to that package name instead. The package name is not necessarily the same as the group id of the dependency.